# Spring Value Injection Into Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, spring-boot

I am very new to spring and I am trying to get a handle on Value injection. I have the following spring boot bean:

```
@Configuration
public class GraphProductionConfig {

    @Value("${database.config}")
    private static String CONFIG;

    @Bean
    public static GraphFactory getGraphFactory(){
         return new GraphProductionFactory();
    }

    public static class GraphProductionFactory implements GraphFactory{
        public Graph buildGraph() {
            TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(CONFIG);
            Graph graph = titanGraph;
            graph.tx().onClose(Transaction.CLOSE_BEHAVIOR.ROLLBACK);
            return graph;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following inside my application.properties file:

```
database.config="conf/titan-cassandra.properties";
```

I am trying to inject `database.config` into `GraphProductionFactory` so that I can use different configurations. I know that injecting into static fields is VERY bad. I have read constructor injection might be possible but I would like my `GraphProductionFactory` to remain static. Any suggestions for how to proceed ?

**Edit:**

I have been able to achieve the desired behaviour using:

```
public static class GraphProductionFactory implements GraphFactory{
    @Value("${database.config}")
    private String CONFIG;

    public Graph buildGraph() {
        TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(CONFIG);
        Graph graph = titanGraph;
        graph.tx().onClose(Transaction.CLOSE_BEHAVIOR.ROLLBACK);
        return graph;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how correct this new approach is.

Comment: You can't use constructor injection in `@Configuration` classes, but you can use parameters on bean methods.

Answer (score 0):

application.propertiesAdd `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean a to your configuration.

```
@Configuration   
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")//location of your property file
public class GraphProductionConfig {

             @Value("${database.config}")
             private static String CONFIG;

            //other bean configuration
            //..
            @Bean
            static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
                return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            }

}
```

Comment: How would this inject the value I need ? `database.config="conf/titan-cassandra.properties";` is inside application.properties. Can I use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ` to get the value ?

Comment: @Fido I thought ,that was your application properties, `PropertySource ("the location of your property file")`

Comment: I should have been more clear the value I am after is inside my application.properties that value just happens to be a String pointing to another config file.

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications:

```
static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceHolderConfigurer()
```

is required for @PropertySource to work so that @Value are injected.

To achieve your objective to have an indirection level for part of your .properties, you have have different solutions:
- as you intended, you specify the name of the final .properties file in a variable injected by @Value, but then you have to add this new property source to the current context and then refresh it if you want the added values to be available in other @Value, this requires access to some "low" level API of Spring context API and careful bean dependency analysis,

- simpler solution is to use one an environment variable (a variable passed at runtime to the JVM using the -D, e.g. -DrunningEnv=dev|test|prod|whatever...) and then using that environment variable as a path component to point to the actual configuration you target.
  Example:

  classpath:configuration/${runningEnv}/cassandra.properties

that you can use in @PropertySource.